# Matching the correct response schema based on a property using discriminator in openAPI document (fails in documentation builders like swagger)

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, openapi-generator, readme.io

I am trying to define a payload schema inside OpenAPI (v3). The payload has two properties, `ruleType` and `pairs`. The schema for the `pairs` is an array of objects. And the schema for those pair objects depends on the `ruleType` which is an enum.

I am able to loosely define this inside OpenAPI as follows

```yaml
components:  
  schemas:
    RuleType:
      type: string
      enum: [Redirect, Cancel, Replace, Headers, UserAgent, Script, QueryParam, Response, Request, Delay]
      default: 'Redirect'
    PAYLOAD:
      type: object
      required: 
        - ruleType
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        description:
          type: string
        ruleType:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/RuleType'
        pairs:
          type: array
          items:
            discriminator:
              propertyName: ruleType
              mapping:
                Redirect: '#/components/schemas/RedirectRulePair'
                Cancel: '#/components/schemas/CancelRulePair'
                Replace: '#/components/schemas/ReplaceRulePair'
                Headers: '#/components/schemas/HeadersRulePair'
                UserAgent: '#/components/schemas/UserAgentRulePair'
                QueryParam: '#/components/schemas/QueryParamRulePair'
                Response: '#/components/schemas/ResponseRulePair'
                Request: '#/components/schemas/RequestRulePair'
                Delay: '#/components/schemas/DelayRulePair'
            oneOf:
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/RedirectRulePair'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/CancelRulePair'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ReplaceRulePair'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/HeadersRulePair'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserAgentRulePair'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/QueryParamRulePair'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ResponseRulePair'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/RequestRulePair'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/DelayRulePair'
    # ... all the rule pair schemas ...
```

But when I import this document inside an API documentation builder like Swagger-UI or Readme.com, it is not able to make this co-relation and there are hence just too many options even after selecting the `ruleType`. [Like this](https://requestly.readme.io/reference/post_rules):

[image: readme.io generated document]

Ideally, since I have defined the mapping inside the OpenAPI doc, after selecting the `ruleType`, the only option available for the `pairs` should be the schema mapped to that `ruleType`

Is this even possible, does anyone know how to define this better or how to define this separately inside these auto documentation tools? Still new to understanding the OpenAPI spec so any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: What behavior would you like to have? Can you explain step-by-step?

Comment: @MaksimEliseev Ideally, since I have defined the mapping inside the OpenAPI doc, after selecting the `ruleType`, the only option available for the `pairs` should be the schema mapped to that `ruleType`. Which is what I was trying to explain with the screenshot. Edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour for the OpenAPI you showed, the API documentation tools all show the complete documentation for an endpoint, which does make sense.

I think (but I haven't tried it) that it's possible to achieve what you are describing by expressing the schema as a series of oneOf options, with the same name, description, status, etc in each of the objects, but the RuleType as a const and only the relevant pairs structure described. The documentation tools will probably then display a choice of schemas to the user, and they'll only see the one that is related. Give it a try - taking a different approach to describing the structure should give you some other options.